# RPI-KYB keyboard model not in keyboard configuration list

Tags: pi-4, keyboard, raspi-config, raspbian-lite

I have a raspberry pi keyboard from the desktop starter kit (Model: `RPI-KYB`). I am running raspbian lite and cannot configure the keyboard correctly. The RPI-KYB model is not in the `raspi-config` list of models. The generic settings are not mapped correctly.

Any idea how to update the list of keyboard configs or which configuration to use for this model?

Comment: *"The generic settings are not mapped correctly"* -> Might be worthwhile to explain exactly which keys do not map properly.

Comment: What country are you in? What layout does your keyboard have?

Comment: US and this is the layout https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2019/04/Getting-started-with-the-Raspberry-Pi-Keyboard-and-Mouse.pdf

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/108163/edit) your question and add additional information there, not in comments.

Comment: In a picture it appears to be a standard 101-key PC keyboard.  The one I looked at is a GB (aka UK) layout as there is a pound sign in place of the pound sign -- £ instead of # that is ;).  In any case, that is in the list available w/ `raspi-config`.